# why does cmds.select ('set1') return "none"?

Tags: python, select, maya

In my Maya scene, I have a set that contains objects a, b and c.

I run this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

curSel = cmds.select ('set1')
print curSel
```

it selects the set's members correctly as stated in Maya's Documentation [page](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/select.html). There it literally says *"# the following selects all the members of set1"*.

Please bear with me, I'm trying to learn, but the looking through the search results is like navigating through a forest of excessive tangential info, that doesn't really help much.

while I have managed to make use of the selection, I need clarification on understanding why is **print curSel** returning "none"? Is there a listing concept that I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: None of the examples show assigning the result of the call, why did you think you should be doing that?

Comment: Is there any member of set1?

Comment: @ Ian - yes the set has 3 members - objects a, b and c

Comment: @ jonrsharpe - I needed to do a for loop for each member of the set. I was able to do a workaround by using

mySel = cmds.ls(sl=1)
curSel = cmds.select ('set1')
for x in mySel:
 ~do something


But I guess it was wrong of me to think that I can access the members of set1 using cmds.select the same way I could use cmds.ls.

Comment: sorry about the messy responses, I'm still learning how to post with the proper indents and spacings. plus im only 2 days into learning scripting in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `cmds.select` on any object, be that a set or a mesh, and it will always return `None`. Even in the documentation it says:

> Return Value:
>
> None

So in this case you can use `cmds.ls(sl = True, l = True)` after the select command to store the objects in a variable.

Or if you are just trying to get objects that are in a set you don't have to bother selecting them at all and use `cmds.sets('set1', q = True)`, which will give you a list of the objects.